# Impossible removing JS:Downloader-FHB trj

Tags: malware, virus

im having big issues removing "JS:Downloader-FHB trj" on my computer, i already tried all software available, and after detecting and removing than the software says that is clean, but is not in reality, i used everything including the adwclear from bleepingcomputer.

The strange thing is that the malware shows when i login the backoffice of my online store (magento), the avast alert shows, and everything on my website cant me touch used because the scripts from the website is not being loaded, is very strange, im quite new at this things of malware., and im sure that is realted with my computer and not the hosting because is only firing on my pc.

Can someone tell me if there is a solution.

Comment: Nuke it from orbit. It's the only way to be sure. Wiping your hard drive and even BIOS clean is the only way to remove persistent malware when all other methods have failed.

Comment: unfortunately, we are not a malware removal forum

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing your magento caches. I had the same malware warning from Avast - after clearing my Magento caches, it went away - I suspect it was false positive of sorts.